# SCOPE_IDENTITY() after TableAdapter Update

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010, tableadapter, scope-identity

I've updated my TableAdapter's advanced options, so it would Refresh the data table.

I'm looking to retrieve the SCOPE_IDENTITY of the new added row, right after I use TableAdapter.Update.

How can this be achieved?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TableAdapter` will insert the `SCOPE_IDENTITY` automatically at the end of the insert statement. The `DataRow` contains the newly created identity value after the insert. Just don't set the PK column before you add the row to the table and update it via the `TableAdapter`.

```
Dim daLocation As New LocationTableAdapter() ' the TableAdapter
Dim newLocation = Location.NewLocationRow() ' the new DataRow

newLocation.Name = "Berlin"
Location.AddLocationRow(newLocation)
' now update the DataTable or the DataRow with the TableAdapter 
Dim numRowsUpdated As Int32 = daLocation.Update(newLocation) 
Dim id As Int32 = newLocation.idLocation ' now the new ID is available
```